# Mysql subquery group by error

Tags: mysql, subquery

I wanted to do a sub query to find out two information. here is the code i got

```
SELECT b.boroughName, SUM(c.crimeCount), 
    (SELECT SUM(c.crimeCount)
    FROM FYP_Borough b JOIN FYP_Crime c on b.boroughID=c.boroughID
    WHERE offenceID=8
    GROUP BY boroughName) AS DrugUse
FROM FYP_Borough b JOIN FYP_Crime c ON b.boroughID=c.boroughID
GROUP BY b.boroughName
```

This is the error i get:
Subquery returns more than 1 row

I want to group by boroughName because otherwise it gives the same value for each of my fields. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.boroughName, SUM(c.crimeCount), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN offenceID=8 THEN c.crimeCount ELSE 0 END) 
 AS DrugUse
FROM FYP_Borough b JOIN FYP_Crime c ON b.boroughID=c.boroughID
GROUP BY b.boroughName
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. How does the Case statement work?

Comment: You are wellcome. 
case 
when condition1 then expression1
when condition2 then expression2
.....
else expressionN
end

It evaluates and returns expression if corresponding condition is true. In this query it is evaluated for every row returing c.crimeCount or zero. Then grouped by depending on your logic.